# Flex / ActionScript Possible to add Empty Array to URLVariables

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, urlvariables

I have tried several different ways, but it seems that it never sends the empty array value to the server

```
      _vars["myObject[array_list][]"] = null;
      _vars["myObject[array_list][]"] = [];
```

It only seems to work if I provide a value (which I am trying to avoid). What I would like for it to do is send the url param: myObject[array_list][]=& (i.e. an empty value)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `_vars["myObject[array_list][]"] = "";`